# WordPress com erro 404

Tags: wordpress

Copiei uma pasta de um site wordpress online e colei em meu servidor local.

Fiz um backup do banco de dados e atualizei meu banco igual ao original. Conexão ok.

Porém, ao tentar acessar o site, ele aparece a página do tema, mas ao invés do conteúdo, aparece o erro 404.

Alguma dica?

Comment: Você já atualizou as configurações no wp-config.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Italo, isso deve acontecer por causa das url em seu banco local estarem com o endereço antigo do site.

Abra o backup do banco de dados em um editor de texto e faça um buscar/substituir para encontrar todas as url antigas e substituir pela sua url local.